# Как настроить автоматическое перекладывание не java файлов в каталог с файлами class?

Tags: java

Использую `Intellij Idea` и `Gradle`. Проблема в том, что в процессе разработки (своей небольшой тестовой программы) я скалываю `xml` файлы прямо в каталог `src` с файлами `java`. При запуске проекта программа ругается, что файла нет, т.к. `java` файл хранится в папке `out`. Как сделать так, чтобы после компиляции мои `java` файлы лежали вместе с `class` файлами ?

Answer (score 1):

По умолчанию, java plugin Gradle использует папку src/main/resources, так что просто создайте её (если она еще не создана) и кладите туда ваши ресурсы.
 Подробнее читайте [в документации.](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_project_layout)

Answer (score 0):

Для этого придуман каталог `resources`, храните файлы там и поучайте их c помощью `getResource()`, они должны копироваться автоматически. Это самый правильный путь, ИМХО.

Answer (score 0):

В build.gradle который в корне проекта (или в модуле если main класс в модуле)

- ...
- build.gradle <---
- module
- - build.gradle <---
- - src\main\java
- ...

Нужно добавить блок

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
            srcDirs "src/main/res"
        }
    }
}
```

То что будет указано в `srcDirs`, можно будет использовать как хранилище для ресурсов и складывать туда медиа, например xml.

И как сказал [Viacheslav Vedenin](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/195998/viacheslav-vedenin) после можно будет обращаться к ним через `getResource()`

Comment: Не нужно добавлять никаких sourceSets блоков. По умолчанию, java plugin в Gradle использует папку src/main/resources. См. https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_project_layout